# set the value of the input field as value of the hidden field using JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This question seem to be very silly! but I am looking for the best answer,

I have a input field and a hidden field. How to set the value of the input field as value of the hidden field?

`<input class="class1" id="id1" name="name1" value="06/30/2015" />`

`<input type="hidden" name="hidden" id="hidden" value="I want the value of above field">`

Comment: On page load? Or when value entered in `input`?

Comment: When value is entered in input @Tushar

Comment: small question to understand the requirement better, why can't we use same fields at both the places? Why are we duplicating the values, moreover one of them is hidden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Please try this**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#id1").change(function(){
        $("#id1").val($("#hidden").val());
    });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Rino_Raj/bLcnx/621/)

Comment: Do you see `jQuery` tag in question or is it mentioned in question

Comment: What if I want to change the value using some Datepicker? blur doesn't work in that case!! @Rino Raj

Comment: @UserAR I have updated the code. Please see the "DEMO"

Answer (score 1):

You can use a change event handler to update the value of hidden field

```js
//set the initial value
hidden.value = id1.value;
```

```html
<input class="class1" id="id1" name="name1" value="06/30/2015" onchange="window.hidden.value=this.value" />
<input type=hidden name="hidden" id="hidden" value="I want the value of above field">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can this by below why, i used onblur for set values from input to hidden. same why you can use different method for this.

Or if you strictly want to use javascript then add one onblur function and do code as i do with callthis() function.

```js
$("#id1").blur(function(){
      $("#hidden").val($(this).val())
      console.log($("#hidden").val());
    });

function callthis(inputobj)
{
  document.getElementById("hidden").value = inputobj.value;
  console.log(document.getElementById("hidden").value)
}
```

```html
<input class="class1" id="id1" name="name1" onblur="callthis(this)" value="06/30/2015" />

<input type="hidden" name="hidden" id="hidden" value="I want the value of above field">
```

Comment: Do you see `jQuery` tag in question or is it mentioned in question